# join two android projects(login and tab screen)

Tags: android

i have two android projects, one is login and 2nd is fragmented (tab) screen with tabs and card, but these two projects are in different laptops ,so how  to combine these two projects in one. so that after login that tab screen should occur.Please help me.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

just take a backup on drive and download in which system you want to and copy paste the code there is no other way to do